# Proving that the induced L1 and L-infinity matrix norms are duals of one another

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{nxn}$. Let $\lVert A \rVert_1 = \max \{\lVert Ax\rVert_1: \lVert x \rVert_1 \leq 1\}$ and $\lVert A \rVert_{\infty}= \max \{\lVert Ax\rVert_{\infty}: \lVert x \rVert_{\infty} \leq 1\}$. How do I show that these two norms are dual of one another?

I tried to show this by showing $$\lVert A \rVert_{\infty} = \max\{Tr(Z^TA): \lVert Z\rVert_1 \leq 1\}$$

and vice versa.

I found out that $Tr(Z^TA) = \sum_{i=1}^n z_i^Ta_i$ where $z_i, a_i$ are the columns of $Z, A$ respectively. So we have that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n z_i^Ta_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \lVert z_i \rVert_1 \lVert a_i \rVert_{\infty} \leq \sum_{i = 1}^n \lVert a_i \rVert_{\infty}$$

since $$1 \geq \lVert Z \rVert_1 = \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} \sum_{i = 1}^n |z_{ij}|$$

From there on, I am stuck. Also, I have no idea how to show the other direction.

Ideally, I should show this using linear-algebraic techniques. I'm not dealing with dual-spaces or anything of the like.

Comment: $c_0^* = \ell^1$, $\ell_1^* = \ell^\infty$

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your notation.

Comment: and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/732839/290189

Comment: I'm not sure how they are equivalent? I think the other question is dealing with sequences and dual spaces, where I'm just trying to show a matrix inequality? Not sure how to show this from the other answer.

Comment: $x \mapsto Ax$ is a linear transformation on $\Bbb{R}^n$, so there exists $v \in \Bbb{R^n}$ so that $v^Tx = Ax \forall x \in \Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't make sense. $v^Tx$ is a scalar, $Ax$ is not.

Comment: My bad.  Sorry for the confusion

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question. The linked question does not deal with the norms *induced* by $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_\infty$.